# How to pass all children of a page into wordpress' "is_page" function?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, conditional-statements, selector, buddypress

i'm trying to implement a redirect for users who are not logged in to a Wordpress site. Currently if users aren't logged in and they are on the page /members, they are redirected. This part works. But I would like to also redirect if the current page is any child page of /members (example: /members/my_profile or /members/your_profile).

I'm trying to also check to see if the page is a child page of /members, how can I pass all of the child pages of /members to a is_page function?

Current code is:

```
function bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect() { 
   if( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'members' )|| is_page( 'activity' )  ) { 
      wp_redirect( home_url( '/register/' ) ); 
      exit(); 
   } 
 } add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bp_logged_out_page_template_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
$parent_id = your parent id here ;

if(! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'members' )|| is_page( 'activity' ) &&($post->post_parent==$parent_id)) {

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bp_is_user()`.  It will return true for any profile page.

http://hookr.io/functions/bp_is_user/

If you intend to distribute your code, don't use `is_page` because the page may have a different name. 
Instead, use `bp_is_members_directory()` to check if you are on the members directory.

http://hookr.io/functions/bp_is_members_directory